# Cannot register AX module

Tags: directshow, regsvr32

I try to register a 64-bit DirectShow filter (*64.AX) in my 64bit Windows 8.1 with

```
regsvr32 MyDirectShowFilter64.ax
```

and it gives me the following error message
[image]

Registering 32bit Filter (*32.ax) works flawlessly:

```
regsvr32 MyDirectShowFilter32.ax
```

It also works under a Windows 10 installation.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a way to make 100% sure my *64.ax filter is correctly build as 64bit?

Comment: You did not post anything to tell for specific problem. A rule of thumb is to disable self-registration in post-build event, set up debugger to start with regsvr32 as a host, and step through `DllRegisterServer` to find the bug.

Comment: The .ax is provided by the hardware vendor and worked under different machines and Win versions. I did not build anything. Therefore I am not able to debug/analyze the code. I expected to find any concrete error message or log-file, but I guess I am out of luck. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to use the Regsvr32 tool and troubleshoot Regsvr32 error messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873), there are two different versions of `regsvr32`:

- The 64-bit version is `%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe`.
- The 32-bit version is `%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe`.

So you might have to enter the full path to `regsvr32`.

Comment: With my understanding I need the first one and being in the \System32 directory and using above command should take the right one. I also tried with entering the complete path for both regsvr32. They both fail with the same error.